# how to call css/html elements in applescript?

Tags: html, css, applescript

I'm trying to make 2 applescripts to change some settings on my IP doorphone.
The doorphone has a web gui. I'm able to login and go to the specific page in Safari.
I can enter the new values, but I can't control the "APPLY" button. 
"Return" doesn't work. How can I do this?

This a part of the sourcecode of the button:

```
<button class="win-command x-apply" rel="tootlip" title="Command with icon with border ring">
<span class="win-commandicon win-commandring icon-disk"></span>
<span class="win-label" data-rs="button/apply"></span>
</button>
```

My applescript:

```
tell application "Safari"
activate
open location "https://10.0.1.207/#directory-phonebook?pageindex=0"
tell application "System Events"
delay 3
keystroke "admin"
keystroke tab
keystroke "1234"
delay 1
keystroke return
delay 3
keystroke tab
delay 1
keystroke tab
delay 1
keystroke "sip:21@10.0.1.201"
end tell
end tell
```

so, after the last keystroke, I have to add the apply-button-click.

Thanks,
Stijn

Comment: Where's your AppleScript code?

Comment: Please [edit] the code into your question

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using JavaScript injection. So you need to add the following line to your AppleScript code after the last keystroke:

```
do JavaScript "document.querySelector('button.x-apply').click()" in document 1
```